# visual studio solution with multiple projects doesnt compile

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, program-entry-point, lnk2019

I first made a program in eclipse (mingw compiler). Now i am translating the code to Visual Studio 2008.
It is one solution with multiple projects. 2 of the projects are for running a (console) program. The other 2 projects are helper classes for those. I have set the project dependencies so that the projects are compiled in the correct order.
I now get an error message LNK2019 and LNK1120 because i have no main in the helper project.
I have tried to compile the helper projects without linking but i cant find out how i should do that. I have tried adding the -c compiler option but unsuccessful. I have also tried to add a useless main to the helper project, but then compilation fails on compiling the real main with "function cannot be overloaded".

How can i fix this so i can have helper projects without a main?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to make a helper library you have to use the project type `Class Library` instead of `Console Application`

Comment: thanks, setting the configuration Properties -> General -> Configuration Type to Static Library fixed the issue

Answer (score 1):

You can compile your helpers as static libraries and link those to your main programs.

Answer (score 0):

1. Right-click on the project(s) in the Solution Explorer to compile them independently of the entire solution. You can also *build* them separately, which performs both compilation and linking.
2. In Windows (I'm not sure about Linux), DLLs still require an entry point. The conventional name is [`DllMain`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583.aspx). If you don't want an entry point, then you should create a static library instead of a DLL, which gets linked into your application at link time rather than dynamically loaded at run-time.

   You'll need to change your project's properties in order to tell it that you are now creating a static library, rather than a dynamic library. This will stop the linker from searching for a `main` function. You might find [this walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235627.aspx) helpful.

   The "function cannot be overloaded" error is presumably because the dummy `main` function that you added has/had the wrong signature.